# Forcing a notification sound, even if muted

Tags: android, android-notifications

i would like to force a sound in a notification even when the phone is muted.
(Yes i know, thats not the concept, but i want a notification from my alarm system if someone broke into my house)

Iam using the Android API 23 on Android 6.0 with HTC one A9s.
From what i read, my only option is:

1. cache current audio settings
2. change to RINGER_MODE_NORMAL and set MAX_AUDIO
3. run Notification
4. restore old audio settings

This works fine, if iam doing a breakpoint in the debug mode and step over every line of my code.
But it doesnt work if i run in the debug mode (everything the same) without a breakpoint. So i think its a timing problem, that the audio manager/or hardware doenst change from muted to unmuted fast enough. Iam not an expert, but thats my conclusion. Any suggestions how to handle that? I could do a sleep or something, but this doenst seem reliable and right.

my current code:

```
// save current audio settings to restore later
int audio_ringermode = audio_mode.getRingerMode();
audio_old_volume =             
audio_mode.getStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_NOTIFICATION);

// set new audio settings
audio_mode.setRingerMode(AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_NORMAL);
 audio_mode.setStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_NOTIFICATION,audio_mode.getStreamMaxVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_NOTIFICATION),0);

// Notification 
NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, ADMIN_CHANNEL_ID)
.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_home_notify) 
.setColor(notification_icon)
.setContentTitle(notification_title) 
.setContentText(notification_text) 
.setAutoCancel(true) 
.setSound(defaultSoundUri);

NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
notificationManager.notify(notificationId,notificationBuilder.build());

// restore old audio settings
audio_mode.setRingerMode(audio_ringermode);
audio_mode.setStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_NOTIFICATION, audio_old_volume ,0);
```

Comment: I don't think `notificationManager.notify` is synchronous.  Perhaps you need to set a better [policy](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/NotificationManager.Policy)?

Comment: [Set the Policy](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/NotificationManager#setNotificationPolicy(android.app.NotificationManager.Policy)).  Make sure you've granted permissions in your manifest.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me even if the phone muted:

```
    private void playSound() {
    MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(mContext, R.raw.ring_message);
    AudioManager am =
            (AudioManager) mContext.getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
    mediaPlayer.start();
}
```